# Why does IE9 require a meta tag to render rounded corners?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

In IE9, which was just released, you need to provide the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` to allow the css `border-radius` to render.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx indicates that the meta tag is not the only way to enable border-radius.  Instead, you can change your doctype.

Read the whole article to determine whether you want to use the doctype or the meta tag, though.